# Autodiscover targets from containers

Tags: docker, prometheus

We have multiple similar win apps running in docker containers. There also more than 1 container for some aplications. Each one has exporter running one the same port inside container (9182).

Is there any way for prometheus in the container to access their metrics automatically without exposing port for each container separatly and adding this targets in prometheus config manually for each service everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Prometheus Operator](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator) and please read the distinction between it and [`kube-prometheus`](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus). The latter includes the former.

A key aspect of the Prometheus Operator is that it uses Custom Resources (e.g. `ServiceMonitor` and `PodMonitor`) to facilitate the automatic inclusion (aka Discovery) of Kubernetes Services (and Pods) into Prometheus.

I've not used it directly but Prometheus also includes Kubernetes service discovery ([`kubernetes_sd_config`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#kubernetes_sd_config)). This includes `nodes`, `services`, `pods`, `endpoints` etc.

Comment: I've talked about simple docker infrastructure, not kuber clusters
But kubernetes sd config helped me to find docker sd config, so thanks for the answer

Comment: You did, my apologies. Glad it was still helpful